# Select a string between two others strings in a file BASH

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I know some ppl asked the same question but I can't get any result,
here is my text:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>emdee five for life</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:powderblue;">
<h1 align='center'>MD5 encrypt this string</h1><h3 align='center'>PeKPATbxnupBGgWTIg5B</h3><center><form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="hash" placeholder="MD5" align='center'></input>
</br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form></center>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to extract 'PeKPATbxnupBGgWTIg5B' from it.
I'm doing `sed -n "/^h3 align ='center'>$/,/^<h3$/p" thefile` but it does not return anything.
Please help me :(

Comment: Please post valid HTML.

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: We don't need the HTML to be valid, i just want to extract a string from it. It would be the same if my text was "This is a text" and I would extract the string between "This" and "text". (sorry if my english is bad, I'm from France)

Comment: I just want to know why my bash command doesn't extract "PeKPATbxnupBGgWTIg5B" from my text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sed command `sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern2/p` *does* work to extract
lines between `pattern1` and `pattern2` inclusive **if** they are
located in the separate lines.
For instance, the following test code:

```
cat <<EOS | sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern2/p'
foo
bar
pattern1
These lines
are printed.
pattern2
baz
EOS
```

outputs:

```
pattern1
These lines
are printed.
pattern2
```

However, the `sed` command above does *not* work if the patterns are
located in the same line.
Moreover, the caret sign `^` and the dollar sign `$` match the start
and end of the line respectively. They do not indicate the positions
of the substring to match.

Would you try the following instead:
(Needless to say I don't intend to parse XML files with `sed`. This
is just a case study of substring extraction with `sed`.)

```
sed -n "s/.*h3 align='center'>\([^<]*\)<\/h3.*/\1/p" thefile
```

The pattern `.*h3 align='center'>\([^<]*\)<\/h3.*` matches with:

- A substring which includes `h3 align='center'` and any preceding
  characters back to the start of the string.
- Followed by a series of any character excluding `<`.
- Followed by a substring which includes `</h3` and any trailing
  characters up to the end of the line.

Then the `s` (substitute) command replaces the matched pattern with
the second substring above. It works to `extract` the second substring
from the matched line.

Let me go in detail about the second patten `\([^<]*\)`.

- The character class `[^<]` matches any character other than `<`.
- The concept `other than <` is necessary to anchor the pattern matching
  just before the following substring `</h3`. Otherwise the matching
  may run over it for the next substring `</h3` due to the nature of
  `greedy match`.
- The asterisk sign `*` is a quantifier to determine the number of repetitions
  of the previous atom. In this case it matches a substring longer
  than 0 composed of any character other than `<`.
- The surrounding parens `\(` and `\)` create `capture group` and the
  surrounded substring can be referred with `\n` (where n is a number
  in the order of appearance) as a replacement.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way would be to use an XML/HTML parser.

If your text was

```
...
<h1 align='center'>MD5 encrypt this string</h1><h3 align='center'>PeKPATbxnupBGgWTIg5B
</h3><center><form action="" method="post">
...
```

then

```
sed -n "/<h3 align='center'>/,/^<\/h3>/p" thefile
```

would return

```
<h1 align='center'>MD5 encrypt this string</h1><h3 align='center'>PeKPATbxnupBGgWTIg5B
</h3><center><form action="" method="post">
```

which is not what you want. The form `/<start>/,/<end>/` matches everything between `<start>` and `<end>` on different lines.

You could use a substitution using a backreference to match your desired string like

```
sed -n "s/.*<h3 align='center'>\(.*\)<\/h3>.*/\1/p" thefile
```

which returns

```
PeKPATbxnupBGgWTIg5B
```

---

Using `grep` that supports perl compatible regular expressions (PCRE), you could use

```
grep -P -o "<h3 align='center'>\K.*(?=</h3>)" thefile
```

- `-P` enable perl compatible regular expressions
- `-o` only print matching parts
- `<h3 align='center'>\K` use a positive lookbehind, the `\K` is used to match `<h3 align='center'>` which  is not included in the match
- `.*` match any characters
- `(?=</h3>)` use a positive lookahead to match `</h3>` which is not included in the match